# how to restrict special chars in REGEXP

Tags: python, regex, django, django-class-based-views

I am doing to validate textbox field. Here the below code i validated like it should contain chars and decimal numbers and spaces only allowed in regexp. But now i want to do like that it should restrict special chars. The below code allowed the special chars. Cany anyone help me to do this

```
  p = re.compile('[a-zA-z0-9_](\w+ ?)(?:([0-9])+([\,\.][0-9]+))?')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "special character"?

Comment: like *^+&@!#$% these things

Comment: None of those characters are explicitly allowed in that RE, maybe it is how you are using it?  By the way, `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (possible typo in your version?), unless you are using the locale flag.

Comment: see i jus want to restrict special chars. Rest of the things are correct which i mentioned the above syntax.

Comment: Just you need to search if if there is a special char in your text like this : `re.compile('.*[*^+&@!#$%]')` if yes should not pass else pass :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use anchors.

```
 p = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-z0-9_](\w+ ?)(?:([0-9])+([,.][0-9]+))?$')
```

Anchors helps to do an exact string match.

Answer (score 0):

`p = re.compile('([^~+&@!#$%]*)')`. Add any other special characters. This would accept everything till you get a special character.

Or use `p = re.compile('^([^~+&@!#$%]*)$')`, which would fail if you have a special character in the textbox.

Comment: both syntax are same which you defined.. then how could it restrict the special chars..

Comment: the 2nd one starts and ends with characters other than special characters. While the 1st one would stop when it gets a special character and hence would return a match.